# parsing string and create Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have the following string pattern: `1:2,2:3`.

This is like array in one string:
The first element is: `1:2`
The second element is: `2:3`

I want to parse it and create a dictionary:

```
1,2 // 0 element in Dictionary  
2,3 // 1 element in Dictionary
```

This is my code:

```
Dictionary<int,int> placesTypes = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (var place in places.Split(','))
{
   var keyValuePair = place.Split(':');
   placesTypes.Add(int.Parse(keyValuePair[0]), int.Parse(keyValuePair[1]));
}
```

Is there the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Using RegEx you may have much better performance if the input is pretty huge. I think (but you should profile) there is not gain if the input isn't too big or if the function isn't called often (because of RegEx parsing/compilation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change it to this:

```
var d = s.Split(',')
         .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
         .ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x[0]), x => int.Parse(x[1]));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = "1:2,2:3".Split(',')
                           .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                           .ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x[0]), 
                                         x => int.Parse(x[1]));
```

Comment: This isn't the best way, cuz parsing on components of dic will be made twice

Comment: Yeah, edit this to `Select` the second split array before calling `ToDictionary` and you've got my +1.

Comment: @Rawling: Is this you were asking?

Comment: @Nikhil Yup, just missing a `)`

Comment: `.Select(x => x.Split(':')` -> `.Select(x => x.Split(':'))`. Sadly some others have c&p your answer and corrected this faster, but you'll still get mine once you fix this.

Comment: @Rawling: Check now. Edited as you wanted. Its working fine, I checked in VS. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = input.Split(new[]{','})
    .Select(s => s.Split(new[]{':'})) 
    .ToDictionary(k => int.Parse(k[0]), v=> int.Parse(v[1]));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/GTKO60478

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# >= 3.5 the ToDictionary LINQ method is the way to go:

```
var dictionary = places.Split(',')
                       .Select(place => place.Split(':'))
                       .ToDictionary(keyValue => int.Parse(keyValue[0]), keyValue => int.Parse(keyValue[1]));
```

Failing that, the following should suffice:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(string value, char pairSeperator, char valueSeperator) 
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (string pair in value.Split(pairSeperator))
    {
        string[] keyValue = pair.Split(valueSeperator);
        dictionary.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting only once, using [MoreLinq](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/).[Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)

```
 Dictionary<int, int> dict = places.Split(',', ':').Batch(2).Select(x=>x.ToArray()).ToDictionary(x=>int.Parse(x[0]),x=>int.Parse(x[1]));
```